Calculate Delays Duration for the Overlapping Records
I want to calculate the duration of these delays in Hours accurately in SQL Server, but the problem is it have some overlapping records.
Trying to remove the overlapping times for these delay between start to end datetime. and also the GAPs it have.
Note : the table have millions of delays
Example-1 data
DELAY STARTDATE ENDDATE 
Delay1 16-12-2023 08:36:00 24-01-2024 17:29:00 
Delay1 18-12-2023 15:46:00 24-01-2024 17:29:00 
Delay1 18-12-2023 15:46:00 25-01-2024 04:46:00 
Delay1 18-12-2023 15:46:00 25-01-2024 04:52:00 
Delay1 24-01-2024 17:29:00 25-01-2024 20:00:00 
Delay1 28-01-2024 08:00:00 29-01-2024 02:00:00 
Delay2 23-12-2023 00:55:00 24-01-2024 20:00:00 
Delay2 23-12-2023 00:55:00 26-12-2023 16:00:00 
Delay2 26-12-2023 16:00:00 24-01-2024 20:00:00 
Delay2 24-01-2024 20:00:00 25-01-2024 20:00:00

Expected Result -
Delay1  990     (972+18)
Delay2  812 


I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Please put sample data in the question; there is an [edit] feature. Please also ensure the data is formatted appropriately. That wall of text would not be useful. Don't forget, as well, to provide expected results alongside your sample data, and demonstrate your attempts, or what you didn't understand  about the content you've read to help you answer the problem yourself

As I stated, "Please also ensure the data is formatted appropriately"; please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

You also did not (re)tag the product you are really using when you added said image.

As already said, a dbms tag is important - especially when DATE/TIME is involved because many products have their own date/time functions.

Please don't use images. Use table markdown

Also specify the expected result. i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

I cannot overstress the importance of knowing which database you are using. This is vital for dates/times because the syntax differs a LOT. Choose the tag that best matches your dbms.

This may help, it creates a table with your sample data and proposes a query https://dbfiddle.uk/LXu6EgZI this is based in postgres but should work in others with minor changes. But note you have not told us what the expected result should be.

When switching @AdrianMaxwell's  fiddle to MS SQL Server, I get "Msg 2738 Level 16 State 2 Line 1
A table can only have one timestamp column. Because table 'Delays' already has one, the column 'EndDate' cannot be added." Which column data type(s) used here?

Can you ever have cases where delays can overlap with one contained entirely within another?  For example StartDate1 ... StartDate2 ... EndDate2 ... EndDate1? This is a gaps and islands problem, but the logic is different if the end dates are not in the same ascending order with respect to the start dates.

To convert the dbfiddle use datetime instead of timestamp see https://dbfiddle.uk/HHlFqlZh I hope you can now see the importance of using the correct tags, formatted sample data and the expected result.

@AdrianMaxwell - It looks like your fiddle uses the same ROW_NUMBER() calculation for both sides of the grp calculation, so (unless I've misread the code) grp would always be zero.

Yes. Thanks for pointing to that. I was more focused on trying to aid in the development of this question.

This is a variation of the gaps and islands problem. The key is identifying where the date/time ranges do not overlap (the gaps) and then grouping and combining those rows which do overlap (the islands).
The gaps can be identified by comparing the start date/time of each row with the  end date/time of the prior row with the help of the LAG() window function. If you set a flag to 1 for each detected gap, the islands can be numbered by calculating running sum of the gap flag using the SUM() window function. It then becomes a simple matter of grouping the rows in each island and calculating the final results.
WITH Gaps AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN StartDate >
            LAG(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Delay ORDER BY StartDate)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsGap
    FROM Data
),
Islands AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(IsGap) OVER(PARTITION BY Delay ORDER BY StartDate) AS GroupNumber
    FROM Gaps
),
Combined AS (
    SELECT
        Delay,
        GroupNumber,
        --MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate,
        --MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate,
        DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(StartDate), MAX(EndDate)) AS DelayHours
        --CEILING(DATEDIFF(second, MIN(StartDate), MAX(EndDate)) / 3600.0) AS DelayHours
    FROM Islands
    GROUP BY Delay, GroupNumber
)
SELECT
    Delay,
    SUM(DelayHours) AS DelayHours
FROM Combined
GROUP BY Delay
ORDER BY Delay

Intermediate (combined) results:



Delay
GroupNumber
StartDate
EndDate
DelayHours




Delay1
0
2023-12-16 08:36:00
2024-01-25 20:00:00
972


Delay1
1
2024-01-28 08:00:00
2024-01-29 02:00:00
18


Delay2
0
2023-12-23 00:55:00
2024-01-25 20:00:00
812



Final results:



Delay
DelayHours




Delay1
990


Delay2
812



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
One open question is exactly how you wish to calculate the delay in hours between the combined start and end date/times. Several options are available:

Hour boundaries: DATEDIFF(hour, StartDate, EndDate)
Rounded down: DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, EndDate) / 3600
Rounded nearest: ROUND(DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, EndDate) / 3600.0, 0)
Rounded up: CEILING(DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, EndDate) / 3600.0)

You should choose the calculation that best fits your requirements.
The above also assumes that the EndDate values will be ascending with respect to ascending StartDate values. The timeline Start1 > Start2 > End1 > End2 is supported, but the timeline Start1 > Start2 > End2 > End1 may cause incorrect gap calculations for cases like Start1 > Start2 > End2 > Start3 > End1 > End3 and produce results that overstate the total delays. Resolving this would require adding logic to eliminate "embedded" ranges like Start2/End2 as a preliminary step.

Thanks, What if we have 2 or more Gaps and Those gaps also have more overlapping records ?

@Shai - I do not understand your question. I believe the above should be able to handle any number of gaps (and any number of islands). Can you put together an example with sample data, apply it to one of the fiddles linked above, and post the resulting fiddle link back here with a description of where expected and actual results disagree?

Suggest you do some testing yourself on data you possess that contains the conditions you want tested.

Got it thanks, it can be closed!
